# The Fastest Way Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation, dijkstra

I need to figure out how to solve this problem. I am using Java but it doesn't matter for now. I don't need any codes since I have to do that myself I just need some advices about the algorithm since I can't find any fast ways to do this.(My solution took too long when compiling)

---

**Question is:**

There are 4 cities. Each has different routes from one to other(16 routes totally)

Going from City 1 to City 4 is different than going to City 1 from City 4(all routes are one-way) that's why they have different values.

I have the list of required times for each road which is totally 16. Actually the list will be typed by the user when the program initiates but you can assume that I have the list for now.

After we got the required times the user chooses a starting and an ending city and the program has to find the minimum duration for that travel.

**Example:**

```
0  18 15 8
18 0  7  3
7  16 0  19
10 14 19 0
```

This is a table of travel durations. i(row) x j(column) and the values show the travel duration from i to j city.

When the user inputs "4 2" which means from city 4 to city 2, the the output as answer should be 14

But when the user inputs "2 1" the the output as answer should be 13(3+10). First from city 2 to city 4 which is 3 hours and than from city 4 to city 1 which is 10 hours and totally it makes 13 hours.

So the chosen route doesn't need to be the direct route any number of routes can be used between two cities but with the most fastest way.

---

This 4x4 table was just an example for 4 cities. (Which is all I have also). The algorithm should work for max 100 cities. The user will type the number of cities before filling the table for travel durations between each of them.

I may find a solution for 4 cities but It doesn't work for 100 cities. I also tried permutation method with java but as I said it took too long to compile. However compiling proccess musn't take longer than 4 seconds.

Sorry for the long and boring question of mine but I hope someone can make a useful suggestion.

Comment: This is the classic http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem in its pure form.

Comment: Use `Dijkstra's` algorithm

Comment: I tried Dijkstra's but since the numbers are too big it takes forever to compile. Check out the last part of my question, the algorithm has to work good for 100 cities.

Comment: If the algorithm is taking forever, you implemented it wrong. It's quite efficient.

Comment: find Dijkstra's Algorithm. Its best way to find shortest path as well as cost

Comment: Well I did that but It didn't work as I expected. Maybe you can give a little example for implementing the Dijkstra's algorithm

Comment: @user1180503 yes try googling : "Dijkstra Java Implementation"

Comment: No I mean how can I implement that algorithm for this example. I know how can I use it in java, I tried it but didn't work. I just can't get the logic for this example with Dijkstra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to do it, so answering this myself. I have managed to make it work by editing the code I have found [here](http://www.algolist.com/code/java/Dijkstra's_algorithm). It works really fast and flawless.